# Splitting a JSON string between 2 TextViews

Tags: java, android, json

My objective is to take a string value and divide it in half to place into 2 different TextViews.  The UI component is to be handled by the ArrayAdapter, though this isn't a must.

This is my target UI:

[image]

So far I got a Java class to handle the JSON response.  I'm jus trying to get this functionality to work before I move onto actually extracting data from USGS.

```
public class QueryUtils {

    private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"metadata\":{\"generated\":1462295443000,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10\",\"title\":\"USGS Earthquakes\",\"status\":200,\"api\":\"1.5.2\",\"limit\":10,\"offset\":1,\"count\":10},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.2,\"place\":\"88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\",\"time\":1454124312220,\"updated\":1460674294040,\"tz\":720,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004vvx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004vvx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":2,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":5.82,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":798,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004vvx\",\"ids\":\",at00o1qxho,pt16030050,us20004vvx,gcmt20160130032510,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.958,\"rms\":1.19,\"gap\":17,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.2 - 88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[158.5463,53.9776,177]},\"id\":\"us20004vvx\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\",\"time\":1453777820750,\"updated\":1460156775040,\"tz\":600,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004uks\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004uks&format=geojson\",\"felt\":null,\"cdi\":null,\"mmi\":4.1,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":572,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004uks\",\"ids\":\",us20004uks,gcmt20160126031023,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.537,\"rms\":0.74,\"gap\":25,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[153.2454,-5.2952,26]},\"id\":\"us20004uks\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.3,\"place\":\"50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\",\"time\":1453695722730,\"updated\":1460156773040,\"tz\":0,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gy9\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gy9&format=geojson\",\"felt\":117,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":5.28,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":695,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gy9\",\"ids\":\",us10004gy9,gcmt20160125042203,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.201,\"rms\":0.92,\"gap\":20,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.3 - 50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-3.6818,35.6493,12]},\"id\":\"us10004gy9\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.1,\"place\":\"86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\",\"time\":1453631430230,\"updated\":1460156770040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gqp\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gqp&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1816,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":6.6,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":1496,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gqp\",\"ids\":\",at00o1gd6r,us10004gqp,ak12496371,gcmt20160124103030,\",\"sources\":\",at,us,ak,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,trump-origin,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.72,\"rms\":2.11,\"gap\":19,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.1 - 86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-153.4051,59.6363,129]},\"id\":\"us10004gqp\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.6,\"place\":\"215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\",\"time\":1453399617650,\"updated\":1459963829040,\"tz\":-420,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004g4l\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004g4l&format=geojson\",\"felt\":11,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":3.92,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":673,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004g4l\",\"ids\":\",at00o1bebo,pt16021050,us10004g4l,gcmt20160121180659,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.413,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":74,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.6 - 215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-106.9337,18.8239,10]},\"id\":\"us10004g4l\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.7,\"place\":\"52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\",\"time\":1452741933640,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":51,\"cdi\":5.8,\"mmi\":6.45,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":720,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebx\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebx,pt16014050,at00o0xauk,gcmt20160114032534,\",\"sources\":\",us,pt,at,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",associate,cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.281,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.7 - 52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[142.781,41.9723,46]},\"id\":\"us10004ebx\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\",\"time\":1452741928270,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":-240,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebw\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebw&format=geojson\",\"felt\":3,\"cdi\":2.2,\"mmi\":2.21,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":573,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebw\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebw,gcmt20160114032528,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":5.492,\"rms\":1.04,\"gap\":16,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-63.3288,-19.7597,582.56]},\"id\":\"us10004ebw\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.2,\"place\":\"74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\",\"time\":1452532083920,\"updated\":1459304875040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004djn\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004djn&format=geojson\",\"felt\":8,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":3.74,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":594,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004djn\",\"ids\":\",us10004djn,gcmt20160111170803,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.139,\"rms\":0.96,\"gap\":33,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.2 - 74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[141.0867,44.4761,238.81]},\"id\":\"us10004djn\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.5,\"place\":\"227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\",\"time\":1452530285900,\"updated\":1459304874040,\"tz\":480,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004dj5\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004dj5&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":7.5,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":650,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004dj5\",\"ids\":\",at00o0srjp,pt16011050,us10004dj5,gcmt20160111163807,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":3.144,\"rms\":0.72,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.5 - 227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[126.8621,3.8965,13]},\"id\":\"us10004dj5\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6,\"place\":\"Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\",\"time\":1451986454620,\"updated\":1459202978040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004bgk\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004bgk&format=geojson\",\"felt\":0,\"cdi\":1,\"mmi\":0,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":554,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004bgk\",\"ids\":\",us10004bgk,gcmt20160105093415,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":30.75,\"rms\":0.67,\"gap\":71,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.0 - Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-136.2603,-54.2906,10]},\"id\":\"us10004bgk\"}],\"bbox\":[-153.4051,-54.2906,10,158.5463,59.6363,582.56]}";

    /**
     * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtils} object.
     * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
     * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryUtils is not needed).
     */

    private QueryUtils() {
    }


    public static ArrayList<Earthquakes> extractEarthquakes() {ArrayList<Earthquakes> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();
        // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
            JSONArray earthquakeArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("features");

            String string = SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE;
            String[] parts = string.split("of");
            String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
            String part2 = parts[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < earthquakeArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentEarthquake = earthquakeArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("properties");

                long time = properties.getLong("time");
                String mag = properties.getString("mag");
                String place = properties.getString("place");
                String date = properties.getString("time");

                earthquakes.add(new Earthquakes(mag,place,time));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }

        // Return the list of earthquakes
        return earthquakes;
    }

}
```

And this is my ArrayAdapter

```
public class EarthquakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Earthquakes> {
    //
    //
    //

//    String A = "of";
//    boolean decide;
//
//    decide = baseJsonResponse.contains(A);

    public EarthquakeAdapter(Context context, List<Earthquakes> earthquakes) {
        super(context, 0, earthquakes);
    }

    private String formatDate(Date dateObject) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("LLL dd, yyyy");
        return dateFormat.format(dateObject);
    }

    private String formatTime(Date dateObject) {
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        return timeFormat.format(dateObject);
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Check if there is an existing list item view (called convertView) that we can reuse,
            // otherwise, if convertView is null, then inflate a new list item layout.
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if (listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.earthquake_list_item, parent, false);
            }


//            if (decide == true)
//            {
//                System.out.println("Admin mode");
//            }
//            else
//            {
//                System.out.println("customer mode");
//            }

            // Find the earthquake at the given position in the list of earthquakes
            Earthquakes currentEarthquake = getItem(position);

            TextView quakePosition = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.quakePosition);
            //quakePosition.setText(currentEarthquake.part1);

            // Find the TextView with view ID magnitude
            TextView magnitudeView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
            // Display the magnitude of the current earthquake in that TextView
            magnitudeView.setText(currentEarthquake.getMagnitude());

            // Find the TextView with view ID location
            TextView locationView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            // Display the location of the current earthquake in that TextView
            locationView.setText(currentEarthquake.getLocation());

            // Create a new Date object from the time in milliseconds of the earthquake
            Date dateObject = new Date(currentEarthquake.getTimeInMilliseconds());

            // Find the TextView with view ID date
            TextView dateView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            // Format the date string (i.e. "Mar 3, 1984")
            String formattedDate = formatDate(dateObject);
            // Display the date of the current earthquake in that TextView
            dateView.setText(formattedDate);

            // Find the TextView with view ID time
            TextView timeView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            // Format the time string (i.e. "4:30PM")
            String formattedTime = formatTime(dateObject);
            // Display the time of the current earthquake in that TextView
            timeView.setText(formattedTime);

            // Return the list item view that is now showing the appropriate data
            return listItemView;
        }
        }
```

Earthquakes.java

```
public class Earthquakes {
    private String mMagnitude;
    private String mLocation;
    private long mTimeInMilliseconds;

    public Earthquakes(String magnitude, String location, Long timeInMilliseconds){
        mMagnitude = magnitude;
        mLocation = location;
        mTimeInMilliseconds = timeInMilliseconds;
    }

    public String getMagnitude(){
        return mMagnitude;
    }

    public String getLocation(){
        return mLocation;
    }

    public long getTimeInMilliseconds() {return mTimeInMilliseconds;}
    }
```

The XML is correct without errors so I didn't feel the need to post those here.

Comment: `String string = SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE; String[] parts = string.split("of");`You are splitting the full JSON, get the field you want `place` for each JsonObject instead.

Comment: How would I get the field I want?

Comment: Ok' I didn't read the rest of the code, You are already reading the `place`in your loop, you are creating an instance with it... why don't you use the instance to do the split ? You already have the full string there.

Comment: You mean inside the for loop?  How would I do it?

Comment: `earthquakes.add(new Earthquakes(mag,place,time));` here you have already recover the place value. So why don't you create a methods into `EarthQuakes` (why plural ?) to recover the splitted value, directly fron the instance, not from the JSON.

Comment: Yes but that's inside the loop.  My apologies, I'm really not getting what you're trying to say.  Can you type out the code that you're trying to imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to split one attribute of the JSON for the Activity. But you use EarthQuakes instances, you should simply use OO to do the job.

I see that you create the list :

```
JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("properties");

long time = properties.getLong("time");
String mag = properties.getString("mag");
String place = properties.getString("place");
String date = properties.getString("time");

earthquakes.add(new Earthquakes(mag,place,time));
```

So Earthquake look like this :

```
public class Earthquakes {
    private String mMagnitude;
    private String mLocation;
    private long mTimeInMilliseconds;

    public Earthquakes(String magnitude, String location, Long timeInMilliseconds){
        mMagnitude = magnitude;
        mLocation = location;
        mTimeInMilliseconds = timeInMilliseconds;
    }

    public String getMagnitude(){
        return mMagnitude;
    }

    public String getLocation(){
        return mLocation;
    }

    public long getTimeInMilliseconds() {return mTimeInMilliseconds;}
    }
```

Add a getter to EarthQuakes for both values you want.

```
public String getDistanceFrom(){ return mLocation.split("of")[0]; }
public String getFrom(){ return mLocation.split("of")[1]; }
```

Then you just need to use those into the adapter. For the correct Element.

*Note : You could create both values in the constructor ( and setter ) instead of splitting `place` each time you ask those, since the listview will call those a lot.*

In the adapter, just all the correcte getter for the correct Textview and you will get the value.

Comment: Yes but "place" is not recognized in the Earthquakes.java

Comment: .... in the constructor of Earthquakes, where are you storing the second argument ? the one you get from the JSON `properties.place`, the one named `place` in the code I get from you.

Comment: @OmarOz You should edit your question with the answer you have post (this is not an answer at all). I have edited my answer, just read and try to do it, this is a basic getter to provide the value you want... There is nothing complicated here.

Comment: I'm a beginner Android developer so it is complicated for me.  I really appreciate the help so far but I want to get this to work as I have a deadline.

Comment: Here, you have already done the Android part, you have the view in Android. The Java part (here in the Bean) is not that hard. You just need to recover the values you want directly from the instance you want to print for one line of the view, in the adapter from `currentEarthquake` instance, just call the new getter for the Textview you want.

Comment: I did that and also took your getters for the Earthquakes.java so its updated.  I also updated the same getters for the TextViews I wanted so that's all fine and well but like I asked, Earthquakes.java does not recognize "place".  How do I come across this?

Comment: Because `place` was the name from the JSON, it is `mLocation` that contain the string "94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea". It is that one that you want to split (I did edit the getters to use `mLocation` ).